# Where does 'stack haddock' place the docs it generates?

Tags: haskell-stack, haddock

Where does `stack haddock` (or `stack build --haddock`) place the documentation that it generates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That depends on where the package that the haddocks are generated for "belongs". Haddocks for "local" packages, that are part of a stack project, will be placed inside the `.stack-work` directory inside the project directory. Haddocks for snapshot packages will be placed in the stack root directory, typically `~/.stack`.

The easiest way to discover the exact path is `stack haddock --open`. For example, run `stack haddock --open base` or `stack haddock --open my-pkg` in a project that contains a package with that name.

Answer (score 0):

The command (non-trivial, does not default to the current package) returns the location which the user then has to copy-paste into an open browser. Not much simpler than navigating to the (deeply hidden address)!
Suggestion: could the stack community add a link in `.stack-work` to the `index.html` files produced? Easy to find and can be opened with a double-click!